# Retain access to old emails if I change mx records

Tags: email

If I point my mx records to my new mail server, new emails will send and receive with it. But if I still have my mail client set up to access the old server (I have not deleted the accounts on old server), will I still be able to access the old emails until I get a chance To copy them?